# Xcode10.1 - Test on many iPhones (no liscense) possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

My Apple Dev account says : "Your Apple Developer Program membership has expired." I can run my xcode projects on my real world iPhone.

I have build an App that should be running on several friends iPhones (different versions, iOS´s etc)for testing in the next time.

So, is it necessary to have a paid dev Account for testing on several devices of other persons/accounts? Maybe that my Apple ID allows the access to my iPhone only without a membership. How long will the test apps be running?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is it necessary to have a paid dev Account for testing on several devices of other persons/accounts?

Yes. The ability to run on a device is exactly what a paid account gets you. A free account lets you run on your own device, but only under very limited circumstances; it is intended as just a way of seeing what iOS development is like.

> How long will the test apps be running?

Hard to say, but you'll find out soon enough. Probably only three or four days, would be my guess.

The correct strategy for distributing apps to your friends' devices is (1) get a paid membership, and (2) create Ad Hoc builds or a TestFlight build.